# multithreading library for iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, multithreading

I have been developing an iPad application in which I want to implement multithreading, so that I can use background threads for network communication.

I tried NSThread and NSOperation but I can't get a proper mechanism for thread communication in NSThread and the application crashes randomly when I use NSOperation and NSOperatioQueue....

There is a library called ThreadWorker but it works only on Mac not iPhone/iPad.

So please tell me a good library or method for multithreading in iPhone!

Thanks

Comment: Fix your bug instead of changing the used classes randomly.

Comment: Agreed.  Its extremely unlikely that its NSThread/NSOperation that aren't working, it will be your code which will fail just as badly with other threading implemenatons.

Comment: Thanks guys multithreading worked using NSInvocationOperation and NSOperationQueue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend ASIHTTPRequest.
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Answer (score 0):

I tell you a good library for network programming:
Multithreaded network programming can be painful. If possible use [CocoaAsyncSocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) for your networking. This provides you nice delegate methods that are executed on your main thread.